# Libraries in Arduino IDE 1.0

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I have a simple program to test out these libraries after upgrading to version 1. The program is linked below as are the libraries. They are for [SHT21](http://pastebin.com/Tv8bZfky) humidity sensors.

I get the following errors when I try to compile the program and libraries.

> In file included from sketch_mar26a.cpp:1: /Applications/Arduino
>   v1.0.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Ports/Ports.h:239: error:
>   conflicting return type specified for 'virtual void
>   UartPlug::write(byte)' /Applications/Arduino
>   v1.0.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:48:
>   error:   overriding 'virtual size_t Print::write(uint8_t)'

- http://pastebin.com/Tv8bZfky All the libraries and program

**Offending section from `ports.h`**

```
public:
UartPlug (PortI2C& port, byte addr)
    : dev (port, addr), in (0), out (0) {}

void begin(long);
byte available();
int read();
void flush();
virtual void write(byte);
```

Offending line from print.h

```
    virtual size_t write(uint8_t) = 0;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could narrow things down to the particular offending sections and post those here? Having us go to an external side to look through all your code is perhaps not the most productive approach. Even though the error most likely directly points out what the problem is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that in Arduino 1.0 the Print interface changed to return a number of bytes 'printed' from its `write` function (previously it didn't return a count). Your function declaration:

```
virtual void write(byte);
```

needs to change to:

```
virtual size_t write(byte); 
// or write(uint8_t) since byte is #defined as uint8_t
```

and the implementation will need to return the number of bytes written.